# JDWP syntax error when using Powershell

Tags: java, windows, debugging, powershell, remote-debugging

Windows 7 x64 and the newest java version (didn't work any better with u21 though)

```
java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
```

When trying to start a java application to debug it remotely I get the following error:

```
java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,address=4000,suspend=n <application>
ERROR: JDWP option syntax error: -agentlib:jdwp=server=y transport=dt_socket address=4000 suspend=n
```

but only when using PowerShell, running the exact same command with cmd.exe works just as expected.

Comment: Is your application in a jar format by any chance?

Comment: @Andrew Nope just trying with a trivial Hello World java program right now. Works fine when just executing it with `java Test` as expected so that's not it.

Comment: @Andrew Ok now that's strange.. running the whole thing not in powershell but "good" old cmd.exe works as expected. So now I'm assuming powershell is doing something? editing question accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try :

```
PS> $a = "java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,address=4000,suspend=n <application>"
PS> Invoke-Expression $a
```

I suppose PowerShell try to interpret something in your command line. This way PowerShell just have to execute. Be carefulk, if you have double quotes in your application name use ` before.

You can also try this in order to paramter your call.

```
$scriptBlock = {java -Xdebug                                                         <# This is comment param 1 #>`
                     -Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,address=4000,suspend=n   <# This is comment param 1 #>`
                     `"$($args[0])`"}                                                <# Application Path #>

$ApplicationName = "c:\un chemin applicatif\toto"
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock  -ArgumentList $ApplicationName
```

---

I found it, just try :

```
PS> $a = "java -Xdebug '-Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,address=4000,suspend=n' <application>"
```

I just inclose -Xrunjdwp param inside ''.

Comment: Hmm no that still leads to exactly the same error, but if I print $a it looks like nothing is expanded by PS [see log](http://paste.pound-python.org/show/z01EREMOF36JisU3sIue/).

Comment: Hmm sadly same error in 32bit version too with all variants. Really strange this.

Comment: @Voo, I found it, just inclose -Xrunjdwp params inside ''

Comment: That works, very nice. Do you know what exactly PS is doing here? I assume it may be using "," as a separator for the argument. Good to keep in mind for future similar problems

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,address=4000,suspend=n <application>
```

Try using:

```
java -agentlib:jdwp=server=y,transport=dt_socket,address=4000,suspend=n <application>
```

The latter is used when the target VM is 5.0 or latter, whilst the forner is for machines with a target VM earlier than 5.0

[Source: Oracle Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/conninv.html#Invocation)

Comment: I'm afraid that's the extend of my knowledge. Sorry.

Comment: Yes very strange that. Let's see if there are some windows experts somewhere who can explain what the hell is going on. Using cmd for now works but god is it awful..

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to figure out why it is not working based on the above answers.
I used following and it worked

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=localhost:9009,server=y,suspend=y
```